# Graph Search problem modelled as Coupon Collector

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, coupon-collector

This is a problem in QuantGuide (named as Graph Search 1):
You are given an undirected graph with 10 nodes. From every node, you are able to access any other node (including itself), all with an equal probability of $\frac{1}{10}$. What is the expected number of steps to reach all nodes at least once (rounded to the nearest step)?
My Approach:
This problem resembles the Coupon Collector problem with 10 distinct toys(here nodes) as we can go from one node to any other node. Hence the expected number of steps resembles the expected number of boxes to collect such that we can have all the toys(nodes) in this case.

The answer would be $nH_n$ where n is 10. The answer should be 29.2896825397. But this answer doesn't pass.

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hint: you already have the first coupon for free.

Comment: Tried this idea but it's incorrect answer. It would be great if you could please post a detailed solution @GiorgosGiapitzakis

Comment: So $nH_n - 1$ is not accepted?

Comment: No it was not accepted

Comment: That's weird. I ran a small Python script to simulate the process and I am getting an answer of $\approx 28.28$ which hints that $10H_{10}-1$ is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know....

Answer (score -1):

It is unclear if the question consider the first step, assuming not, then the answer should be $nH_n$ where $n=10$.

$$nH_n=10H_{10}\approx  
29.289682539682538 \approx 29$$

where the last approximation is due to rounding to the nearest step.

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't pass. Tried this but didn't accept answer

Comment: did you key in $29$?

Comment: Yes that was my first answer

Comment: perhaps try it again. possibly with a different computer/ browser? It's very likely a bug. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Tried it on a friend's laptop still didn't work even after using different browser.

Comment: hmmm... it works on mine.

Comment: Weird. It doesn't work for me, either – none of 28, 29 or 30 works.

Comment: That is indeed very weird....  I just tried again and it works again.  I have reported a possible bug with the site. Just to be sure, the url is https://www.quantguide.io/questions/graph-search right?